# Angular breaks jQuery slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm working on this [template](http://velikorodnov.com/html/flatastic/index.html) and after including angular in application a lot  of functionality is broken. A somehow managed to fix them a lot, but I can not get this slide show to work properly.

This is my HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="images/fav.ico">
    <!--stylesheet include-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/camera.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/owl.transitions.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/jquery.custom-scrollbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/lightbox.css">
    <!--font include-->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
<!--slider-->
<div class="camera_wrap m_bottom_0" ng-controller="slideShowCtrl" ng-show="slideShow()">
    <div data-src="images/slide_02.jpg" data-custom-thumb="images/slide_02.jpg">
        <div class="camera_caption_1 fadeFromTop t_align_c d_xs_none">
            <div class="f_size_large color_light tt_uppercase slider_title_3 m_bottom_5">Meet New Theme</div>
            <hr class="slider_divider d_inline_b m_bottom_5">
            <div class="color_light slider_title tt_uppercase t_align_c m_bottom_45 m_sm_bottom_20"><b>Attractive &amp; Elegant<br>HTML Theme</b></div>
            <div class="color_light slider_title_2 m_bottom_45">$<b>15.00</b></div>
            <a href="#" role="button" class="tr_all_hover button_type_4 bg_scheme_color color_light r_corners tt_uppercase">Buy Now</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-src="images/slide_01.jpg" data-custom-thumb="images/slide_01.jpg">
        <div class="camera_caption_2 fadeIn t_align_c d_xs_none">
            <div class="f_size_large tt_uppercase slider_title_3 scheme_color">New arrivals</div>
            <hr class="slider_divider type_2 m_bottom_5 d_inline_b">
            <div class="color_light slider_title tt_uppercase t_align_c m_bottom_65 m_sm_bottom_20"><b><span class="scheme_color">Spring/Summer 2014</span><br><span class="color_dark">Ready-To-Wear</span></b></div>
            <a href="#" role="button" class="d_sm_inline_b button_type_4 bg_scheme_color color_light r_corners tt_uppercase tr_all_hover">View Collection</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-src="images/slide_03.jpg" data-custom-thumb="images/slide_03.jpg">
        <div class="camera_caption_3 fadeFromTop t_align_c d_xs_none">
            <img src="images/slider_layer_img.png" alt="" class="m_bottom_5">
            <div class="color_light slider_title tt_uppercase t_align_c m_bottom_60 m_sm_bottom_20"><b class="color_dark">up to 70% off</b></div>
            <a href="#" role="button" class="d_sm_inline_b button_type_4 bg_scheme_color color_light r_corners tt_uppercase tr_all_hover">Shop Now</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-view></div>

<!--scripts include-->
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/retina.js"></script>
<script src="js/camera.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.custom-scrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="js/sortable.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-file-upload.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-file-upload-shim.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="app/factory.js"></script>
<script src="app/filters.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

My controller

```
controllers.slideShowCtrl = function($scope, $location){
    $scope.slideShow = function(){
        if($location.url() == '/' || $location.url() == '/home'){
            $scope.slideShowView = true;
            return true;
        }else{
            $scope.slideShowView = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is jQuery for creating slideshow

```
// camera slideshow
(function(){
    var cs = $('.camera_wrap');
    if(cs.length){
        cs.camera({
            height: '41%',
            navigation: true,
            pagination: true,
            playPause:false,
            thumbnails: false,
            time: 4000,
            transPeriod : 1000,
            navigationHover: false,
            onLoaded: function() {
                var image = $('.camera_wrap .camera_src > [data-src]'),
                    len = image.length,
                    bullet = $('.camera_wrap .camera_pag_ul > li');
                if(bullet.find('.custom_thumb').length) return;
                for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
                    bullet.eq(i).append('<div class="custom_thumb tr_all_hover"><img src="' + image.eq(i).data('custom-thumb') + '" alt=""></div>');
                }
                bullet.on("mouseenter mouseleave",function(){
                    $(this).children('.custom_thumb').toggleClass("active");
                });
            }
        });
        cs.find('.camera_prev').append('<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>');
        cs.find('.camera_next').append('<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>');
    }
})();
```

The problem is here. On first load or reload (f5), slider looks ok and plays well.

[image: Slider OK]

After clicking trough page and again visiting home (#/home), slider sometimes break, sometimes don't, sometimes it fixes by him self.

[image: Slider broken]

And again after refreshing web page slider works ok and plays well.

If you guys need any additional chunk of code, let me know and I will provide.

Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to make a fiddle/plunker ?

Comment: sorry, but i don't believe that plunker is possible here... I believe there are to many dependencies, etc.... I hope some one will see the problem in that jquey code and he will know how to change it to work with angular

Comment: try to put ur jquery in jquery's no conflict code.  see if this fix ur problem. $.noConflict() ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorically when you put a JQ slideshow in angular view. You need to init everytime you access the view. Because on view/route changes your slideshow will be discarded from DOM, therefore all the content and instance of your slideshow will be discarded too.

> The problem is here. On first load or reload (f5), slider looks ok and plays well.

Yes it should work because slideshow got initial welly

> After clicking trough page and again visiting home (#/home), slider sometimes break, sometimes don't, sometimes it fixes by him self.

The slide does not initial properly because it got discard from DOM when route/view changes

=> To make to work just simply re-init it again exactly after your view rendered.

```js
// This is a dirty patch up, and only showing the fix in most basic way. So you could understand the concept of angular with other DOM manipulation like JQ.
// You should try to study more about DOM manipulation in angular. And for better solution, you can go with directive
controllers.slideShowCtrl = function($scope, $location, $timeout){
    $scope.slideShow = function(){
        if($location.url() == '/' || $location.url() == '/home'){
            $scope.slideShowView = true;
            return true;
        }else{
            $scope.slideShowView = false;
            return false;
        }

        // I just putting slideshow initial right after $scope.slideShow() return true.
        // To make sure slideshow got initial after the ng-show condition return true.
        $scope.$watch(function () {
            return $scope.slideShow();
        }, function (isShow) {

            // This $timeout to 100% sure slideshow initial only happen after view got all its base content rendered
            $timeout(function () {
                if(isShow){
                    var cs = $('.camera_wrap');
                    if(cs.length){
                        cs.camera({
                            height: '41%',
                            navigation: true,
                            pagination: true,
                            playPause:false,
                            thumbnails: false,
                            time: 4000,
                            transPeriod : 1000,
                            navigationHover: false,
                            onLoaded: function() {
                                var image = $('.camera_wrap .camera_src > [data-src]'),
                                    len = image.length,
                                    bullet = $('.camera_wrap .camera_pag_ul > li');
                                if(bullet.find('.custom_thumb').length) return;
                                for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
                                    bullet.eq(i).append('<div class="custom_thumb tr_all_hover"><img src="' + image.eq(i).data('custom-thumb') + '" alt=""></div>');
                                }
                                bullet.on("mouseenter mouseleave",function(){
                                    $(this).children('.custom_thumb').toggleClass("active");
                                });
                            }
                        });
                        cs.find('.camera_prev').append('<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>');
                        cs.find('.camera_next').append('<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>');
                    }
                }
            }, 0)

        })
    }
}
```

**P.S.** 
please aware that, since we do not have any `fiddle/plunker` so to make sure the solution work, I apply some tricks that will put the highest possiblity for my answer to providing a workding code. You can try to remove `$timeout` to see if it worked

Comment: Good job, dude. Yes i'm new with JS and DOM, this is my first AngularJS application. I see what i need to do now and where is the problem. Thx for explanation

Answer (score 1):

I think creating a directive for slideshow can solve this problem.

I have faced this type of problem with swiper slider. After create directive solve my problem.

your directive

```
        angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('cameraSlider', function($timeout){
      return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        templateUrl: function(element, attrs) {

                return attrs.templateUrl | 'your_remplate_url.html'; 
        }
       link: function($scope, element, attrs){
        $timeout(function(){

        element.camera({
            height: '41%',
            navigation: true,
            pagination: true,
            playPause:false,
            thumbnails: false,
            time: 4000,
            transPeriod : 1000,
            navigationHover: false,
            onLoaded: function() {
                var image = $('.camera_wrap .camera_src > [data-src]'),
                    len = image.length,
                    bullet = $('.camera_wrap .camera_pag_ul > li');
                if(bullet.find('.custom_thumb').length) return;
                for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
                    bullet.eq(i).append('<div class="custom_thumb tr_all_hover"><img src="' + image.eq(i).data('custom-thumb') + '" alt=""></div>');
                }
                bullet.on("mouseenter mouseleave",function(){
                    $(this).children('.custom_thumb').toggleClass("active");
                });
            }
        });

        element.find('.camera_prev').append('<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>');
        element.find('.camera_next').append('<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>');
        },200)

       }
      };

})
```

now you can use `camera-slider` class with camera-wrap class

Comment: Please provide example for this case.